# Enter my own image if it is not null - if another image if it is null

Tags: asp.net

such that I work with asp.net but for example if my user no database in their img user tablen so it must display a different image on the page.

for example, if the user's picture is null in tablen then the show "missing.png" but if it has a picture called "blabla.png" so it will show the image,.

i have try its here:

```
<%# Eval("img") %>
```

I can not comment more on it here.

Comment: Your question isn't very understandable. Can you please clean up the wording, perhaps have a bilingual friend take a look at it?

Comment: i mean its her: `<img src="profil-img/<%# (Eval("img") != null ? Eval("img").ToString() : ("tomt/team-111.png").ToString()) %>">`

Why its not work for me?

Comment: Describe not working. Are you getting an exception? What does the resulting HTML look like on the client?

Comment: @mason for example if I have nothing in the database it will show "team-111.png" but it shows me not to the image in some manner.

Comment: You still didn't answer my question. What does the resulting HTML look like?